# Try to get a possibly existing HTML tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse some HTML:

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css('.blockGroup--posts .block')[2..30].each do |article|
    title = article.at('h2').text # or h3, h4
    image = article.at('.section-content img')['src']  # may not exist
```

The problem is that sometimes the title may appear in `h2` or `h4` tags, so

```
title = article.at('h2').text
```

would report

```
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
```

The same goes for `image`. Sometimes there is no image in an article, and it will report an error too.

How can I make Nokogiri get these elements and continue running? Or can I use callbacks if these elements do not exist?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal example of HTML that matches your question. This helps us help you. Failing to do that wastes our time as we try to create something from scratch. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, you can always `try` like this:

```
title = article.at('h2').try(:text) || "your any alternative methods can be called here"
```

Can be same for image as well.

`try` will return nil or value and it will help you to avoid exception raising.

Comment: But how can I alternate between `h2`/`h3`/'h4'?, its title may appear in any of these.

Comment: And how do I try `['src']`?

Comment: not this way.. you could try see if the the node is not nil then you can check for [..]

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
title = article.at('h2,h3,h4').text
```

Comment: This will still raise an exception if there is no `h2`, `h3` or `h4` tag. Adding a trailing `rescue nil` or `rescue ''` will deal with that, otherwise it's necessary to check to see if the `at` returned `nil` before trying `text`.

Comment: You generally want the exception. It means that your assumption (that title is always in h[2-4]) was wrong and you need to re-evaluate.